# Inject cookies using iframe in multiple websites

Tags: javascript, security, cookies

I have an iframe, says it's hosted at example.com, and I want siteA.com and siteB.com to have the same cookie, I plan to embed iframe (example.com) into siteA and siteB, is that possible? As I know cookie is per domain only.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you control siteA and siteB. If you cannot make changes to them, this is not possible.

Otherwise, you can leverage [two way iframe communication](https://gist.github.com/pbojinov/8965299) to send siteA / siteB a message with the cookie value, which you then write.